# Making custom scenes using sprite kit and not using auto layout

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, device

My app layout is too complex to work with auto layout. I wondering how to create different scenes within a spritekit  template in order to customize and ensure the game will look properly on every device. In a single view application this is easy because I only have to use multiple storyboards. While using sprite kit however,there are scenes and I was wondering how to go about creating the game for every individual screen as opposed to using auto layout. What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

Sprite Kit scenes are presented by a special kind of UIView, [SKView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/), and do not use Auto Layout. Only UIKit does - Auto Layout handles the arrangement of UIViews.

Try looking into Xcode's Level Editor (which is like Interface Builder, only for Sprite Kit). I've found [a Swift tutorial](https://dezwitter.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/spritekit-with-swift-introducing-the-level-editor/) which might be appropriate. Try playing around with it for a little bit.

If you would like a more specific answer, please be more specific about the screens/methods you are planning on using.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Having said that, you CAN position an SKView with AutoLayout. However, the gotcha is that because you don't know the dimensions of the SKView when you are adding the constraints, you have to wait until you do know the dimensions before you can create and add an SKScene to the SKView. For this, have the viewController wait for didLayoutSubviews, then get the dimensions, create the SKScene etc.